# Can't return Promise value outside of Axios call

Tags: vue.js, promise, axios, vuex

I want to get my value to be returned outside, for displaying it on my vue side, and i dont get it..

my getter in state file (vueX)

```
getTotalPrice: (state) => {
        var totalPrice = axios.get("http://" + url + "/meals/")
            .then((meals) => {
                var price = 10

                //ignore this for simplicity ---------------
                state.all_orders.forEach((order) => {
                    price += order.quantity * meals.data.find(elem => elem.id === order.meal_id).price
                })
                //------------------------------------------


                return price
            })

        return totalPrice
    }
```

it should return 10 as total price and i get it in console, but still get `[object Promise]` in vue side

Thanks for your help !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because before the promise is resolved, you are trying to return the totalPrice which is nothing but a unresolved promise.

I insist you to use async-await in this case

```
getTotalPrice: async (state) => { // change added
        var totalPrice = await axios.get("http://" + url + "/meals/") //change added
            .then((meals) => {
                var price = 10;
                //ignore this for simplicity ---------------
                state.all_orders.forEach((order) => {
                    price += order.quantity * meals.data.find(elem => elem.id === order.meal_id).price
                })
                //------------------------------------------
                return price;
            })

        return totalPrice;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Vuex allows us to define "getters" in the store. You can think of them as computed properties for stores. Like computed properties, a getter's result is cached based on its dependencies, and will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.
> [vuex manual](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)

Getters can not contain async functionality. You should fetch data from a server  in the actions section of a vuex module. Move the axios part there and store the data with a mutation and then calculate the total price using a getter.